# What is Carry in Math function in PLC?

Tags: plc

What does **"Carrey"** do in a Math instruction?

Take the following as an example: summation of two binaries give birth to something extra call CY besides the result value. So, 1+ 2 = 3 + some Carry?

The documentation simply says: "If the addition results in a carry, the Carry Flag will turn O" given no explanation of what is a carry, and what is a Carry Flag. What are they and what are the difference if I perform an addition instruction with or without a Carry?

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind, KMC, that the Omron manuals (in fact, all PLC manuals) assume that you are an electrical engineer and already know a lot of these things.  I know it probably feels like they're writing a cruddy manual but perhaps after the last few days it seems it's maybe a bit in the deep end for a start.  A good text on digital logic might be a better start : http://www.mhhe.com/engcs/electrical/brownvranesic/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Carry is the extra bit that is needed to represent the full result of the addition.

If you for example add two 16  bit values, the result needs to be 17 bits to represent every possible outcome.

The carry flag is also used when you chain additions of values larger than the register size. If you have 32 bit values and you can only do 16  bit additions, you add the lower halves of the values first, then the higher halves with the carry from the first addition:

```
Rlo = Alo + Blo
Rhi = Ahi + Bhi + CY
```

The lower halves would be added as unsigned values, and the higher halves would be added as signed or unsigned values with an instruction that uses the carry flag.